# Adult-sized alien child and child-sized alien adult

Tags: story-identification, tv

In an episode from a late 1970s to mid 1980s  sci-fi series, the story revolved around an odd couple: a child-sized adult alien and an adult-sized child alien. What else I recall of the story is that the aliens' maturation follows the opposite path of that of humans. Children are adult sized and diminish to child size as they reach adulthood. The story is absurd and almost embarrassing, yet this is what I recall.

The name of the alien child may have been spelled and pronounced "Rokkos." I'm not entirely sure of the spelling and it could be a variant: Roccos, Rokos, or something similar. After several decades my memory of its pronunciation may have faded, though I am certain that the name began with an 'r,' had two vowels, both 'o,' and concluded with an 's.' Many google searches brought me completely unrelated results such as Rocco's Pizza and Spanish grocery stores.

One final detail is that, as per 1980's plastic aesthetics, both child and adult alien were clothed in golden gauze tunics and baggy pants with equally ridiculous gold-colored nylon page boy wigs.

Comment: Be careful when creating new tags, not everything needs a tag and you’re also recreating ones that already exist. Some of the ones you’ve created should have shown the correct ones in the auto completion.

Comment: Mork and Mindy?  Babies from Ork are born (hatched from giant Eggs) as fully grown adults and get younger as they age.  The baby, Mearth, was played by Johnathan Winters

Comment: Was it maybe an episode of [Mork and Mindy?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mork_%26_Mindy)  The character played by Jonathan Winters was born old and got younger.

Comment: @JRE I would have suggested Mork and Mindy too, were it not for the descriptions of clothing and wigs

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is an episode from the second season of *Buck Rogers in the 25th Century*, "The Golden Man".

Wikipedia only has this brief description:

> After finding a lifepod containing a golden-skinned boy, the Searcher drifts into an asteroid field and becomes stuck against one of the rocks. The only way to free the ship may reside in the strange molecular-altering powers of the boy's companion, the "Golden Man", who is being held captive on a nearby planet inhabited by a penal colony. Once the criminals learn of the alien's powers, they force him to repair a makeshift spacecraft so they can escape. Buck and the golden boy must rescue the golden man from his captors before the Searcher is destroyed.

but [other reviews](https://christopherlbennett.wordpress.com/2018/01/29/buck-rogers-in-the-25th-century-s2-reviews-mark-of-the-saurian-the-golden-man-spoilers/) and [summaries](http://buckrogersguide.blogspot.com/2014/02/ep-207-golden-man-february-19-1981.html) do talk about the backward aging and name the taller one as "Relcos", which is pretty close to what you remember.

Plus, the wigs:
[image]

Comment: I saw the question on my phone and this Buck Rogers episode came to mind immediately. So I figured I’d write an answer as soon as I got home, but I was stuck in traffic for an hour. Kudos for the picture. Those wigs were even worse than Hawk’s hair.

Comment: You got it. Now to forget it. For some reason I've been having flashbacks of Buck Rogers and its contemporaries lately. Fortunately I looked at very little of it when it came out and its very forgettable material. Also, thanks to Tonny for the reminder about the man with the chicken feather wig and black feather eyebrows.

Comment: Yes, that title immediately came to my mind.  Many people have complained about how impossible it would be for aliens to grow smaller as they got older.  
 However, that, while very implausible, is not nearly as impossible as their ability to biologically transmute matter from one element to another and control energies equal to multiple fusion bombs!